# Inappropriate value for attribute "network_interface_id": string required

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on resources.tf line 387, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "main":*
 387:   network_interface_id = module.linuxservers.vm_ids
    |----------------
    | module.linuxservers.vm_ids is tuple with 3 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "network_interface_id": string required
```

hi, i am trying to associate my 3 Azure VM to the LoadBalancer backend pool but getting below above error can you please guide me on this, my code is below.

**Resource.tf**

```
module "linuxservers" {
  source              = "Azure/compute/azurerm"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  vm_hostname         = "Elastic"
  nb_instances        = 3
  nb_public_ip        = 0
  remote_port         = "22"
  admin_username      = var.admin_username
  vm_os_publisher     = "OpenLogic"
  vm_os_offer         = "CentOS"
  vm_os_sku           = "7.5"
  vm_size             = "Standard_D2as_v4"
  ssh_key             = "./putty_key.pub"
  vnet_subnet_id      = data.azurerm_subnet.elasticsearch.id
  tags                = var.tags

}
resource  "azurerm_lb" "main"{
  name                  = "Elastic_LB"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
    
    frontend_ip_configuration{
      name =    "FrontEndIP"
      subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.elasticsearch.id
    }
  
}
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "main" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.main.id
  name                = "BackEndAddressPool"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "main" {
  ip_configuration_name   = "Configuration-VMs"
  network_interface_id = module.linuxservers.vm_ids
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.main.id
}
```

**Module/main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm-linux" {
  count                         = ! contains(list(var.vm_os_simple, var.vm_os_offer), "WindowsServer") && ! var.is_windows_image ? var.nb_instances : 0
  name                          = "${var.vm_hostname}-${count.index}"
  resource_group_name           = data.azurerm_resource_group.vm.name
  location                      = coalesce(var.location, data.azurerm_resource_group.vm.location)
  availability_set_id           = azurerm_availability_set.vm.id
  vm_size                       = var.vm_size
  network_interface_ids         = [element(azurerm_network_interface.vm.*.id, count.index)]
  delete_os_disk_on_termination = var.delete_os_disk_on_termination



  dynamic identity {
    for_each = length(var.identity_ids) == 0 && var.identity_type == "SystemAssigned" ? [var.identity_type] : []
    content {
      type = var.identity_type
    }
  }

  dynamic identity {
    for_each = length(var.identity_ids) > 0 || var.identity_type == "UserAssigned" ? [var.identity_type] : []
    content {
      type         = var.identity_type
      identity_ids = length(var.identity_ids) > 0 ? var.identity_ids : []
    }
  }

  storage_image_reference {
    id        = var.vm_os_id
    publisher = var.vm_os_id == "" ? coalesce(var.vm_os_publisher, module.os.calculated_value_os_publisher) : ""
    offer     = var.vm_os_id == "" ? coalesce(var.vm_os_offer, module.os.calculated_value_os_offer) : ""
    sku       = var.vm_os_id == "" ? coalesce(var.vm_os_sku, module.os.calculated_value_os_sku) : ""
    version   = var.vm_os_id == "" ? var.vm_os_version : ""
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "osdisk-${var.vm_hostname}-${count.index}"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    managed_disk_type = var.storage_account_type
  }

  dynamic storage_data_disk {
    for_each = range(var.nb_data_disk)
    content {
      name              = "${var.vm_hostname}-datadisk-${count.index}-${storage_data_disk.value}"
      create_option     = "Empty"
      lun               = storage_data_disk.value
      disk_size_gb      = var.data_disk_size_gb
      managed_disk_type = var.data_sa_type
    }
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${var.vm_hostname}-${count.index}"
    admin_username = var.admin_username
    admin_password = var.admin_password
    custom_data    = var.custom_data
  }

  }
  }

  tags = var.tags

  boot_diagnostics {
    enabled     = var.boot_diagnostics
    storage_uri = var.boot_diagnostics ? join(",", azurerm_storage_account.vm-sa.*.primary_blob_endpoint) : ""
  }
}
```

**module/output.tf**

```
output "vm_ids" {
  description = "Virtual machine ids created."
  value       = concat(azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-windows.*.id, azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-linux.*.id)
}

output "network_security_group_id" {
  description = "id of the security group provisioned"
  value       = azurerm_network_security_group.vm.id
}

output "network_security_group_name" {
  description = "name of the security group provisioned"
  value       = azurerm_network_security_group.vm.name
}

output "network_interface_ids" {
  description = "ids of the vm nics provisoned."
  value       = azurerm_network_interface.vm.*.id
}

output "network_interface_private_ip" {
  description = "private ip addresses of the vm nics"
  value       = azurerm_network_interface.vm.*.private_ip_address
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure it for each element from 'ids` so it should be like:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "main" {
  count                 = var.node_count
  ip_configuration_name   = "Configuration-VMs-${count.index}"
  network_interface_id = element(module.linuxservers.vm_ids, count.index)
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.main.id
}
```

I'm not sure about syntax here `element(module.linuxservers.vm_ids, count.index)`, because I don't see where this output is defined (maybe I'm blind). But this is pretty much what you need.

Comment: ```element(module.linuxservers.vm_ids, count.index) ``` its define in module/main.tf ok let me give a try

Comment: Yes, but similar needs to be done in`azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association`

Comment: ```
Error: Error: `properties` was nil for Network Interface "" (Resource Group "MyResourceGroup")

  on resources.tf line 385, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "main":
 385: resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "main" {
```

Comment: Can you show me how `vm_ids` is defined? Please edit your question for that.

Comment: I just wonder if you don't have null values in `vm_ids`

Comment: i don't get it. actually i have run terraform init and this linuxserver module automatically downloaded. i never wrote anything on this i am just simply creating Load Balancer and associated to these 3 Linux VM.

Comment: But you have here also reference to windows machines `concat(azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-windows.*.id, azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-linux.*.id)` Can you remove this and try with `value       = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-linux.*.id`?

Comment: yes 1 windows vm and 3 linux vms and load balancing is only for linux vms but yes i can temporarily remove winodws part and give a try

Comment: issue resolved. `resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "main" {
  count                 = var.node_count
  ip_configuration_name   = "Elastic-ip-${count.index}"
  network_interface_id = element(module.linuxservers.vm_ids, count.index)
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.main.id
}`